# How to parameterize the PointSymbolizer in a SLD Style?

Tags: geoserver, wms, point, sld, cql

I am trying to clean my `GeoServer`  deleting some redundant `SLD Styles`.

All this styles work in the same way, they assign some image (different for every style, which name is hardcoded in every style) to every point in the layer, passing the image as an `OnlineResource`, later as a `ExternalGraphic` and finally as a `PointSimbolizer`.
I want to replace all this styles by one generic style who have the image name as a parameter.

TODO: Example

In my First attempt I tried to replace the hard coded name of the image using the `ogc:Function name="env"`  and passing the name as a `WMS parameter`, but this fail because the name is in the `OnlineResource` tag.

My Second attempt whas to use a `CQL_FILTER` to pass the name, but i cant add the name as a feature of the layer.

```
     <Rule>
      <Title>Potencial hidráulico</Title>
      <MinScaleDenominator>3000000</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>100000000</MaxScaleDenominator>
       <PointSymbolizer>
         <Graphic>
           <ExternalGraphic xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
             <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="${IMG}"  />
             <Format>image/png</Format>
           </ExternalGraphic>
           <Size>10</Size>
         </Graphic>
       </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

Calling with this URL:

[http://192.168.72.26:8080/geoserver/[workspace]/wms?&CQL_FILTER=IMG=%27gen_hiroelectrica.png%27&service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=[workspace]%3A[layer]](http://192.168.72.26:8080/geoserver/%5Bworkspace%5D/wms?&CQL_FILTER=IMG=%27gen_hiroelectrica.png%27&service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=%5Bworkspace%5D%3A%5Blayer%5D)

Giving me this error:

2022-06-06 11:43:24,712 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: The requested Style can not be used with this layer.  The style specifies an attribute named 'IMG', not found in the '[workspace]:[layer]' layer

Are any of those way correct? There is other alternative way to parameterize the name of the image? It is even possible (or recommended) to replace all the redundant styles by one generic style?

Comment: Please show us what you tried and what went wrong

Comment: I am going to add the example when I come back to the office this monday. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

If I get your request correctly, you're looking for a special customization of SLD (not standard) that is called "dynamic symbolizers" in GeoServer. See this old blog post about it (very old, SLD got ruined during the various migrations in the last 14 years):

https://geoserver.org/tips%20and%20tricks/2008/12/08/dynamic-symbolizers-part-1.html

In short, functionalty allows to embed a generic CQL expression inside the URL of a external graphic:

> [http://www.usautoparts.net/bmw/images/states/tn_${strToLowerCase(STATE_ABBR)}.jpg](http://www.usautoparts.net/bmw/images/states/tn_$%7BstrToLowerCase(STATE_ABBR)%7D.jpg)

There are however downsides to this approach: GeoServer will not be able to generate a legend image any more, as the contents of it now depend dynamically on the values of your data.